# Share mp3 file in swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, mp3, share

I want to share MP3 file when long pressed in a collection view cell. I wrote the below code but It returns nothing. I mean when I sent an e-mail to myself. It doesn't include the MP3 file and also I can't see the WhatsApp part.

```
 let r = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: temp_url!)
    //var activityItems: [Any] = [temp_url!]
    let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [r], applicationActivities: nil)
    activityViewController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.view // so that iPads won't crash

    // exclude some activity types from the list (optional)
     let excludeActivities = [UIActivityType.airDrop, UIActivityType.print, UIActivityType.assignToContact, UIActivityType.saveToCameraRoll, UIActivityType.addToReadingList, UIActivityType.postToFlickr, UIActivityType.postToVimeo, UIActivityType.postToFacebook, UIActivityType.message, UIActivityType.postToWeibo]
    activityViewController.excludedActivityTypes = excludeActivities

    // present the view controller
    self.present(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)


    // exclude some activity types from the list (optional)
    activityViewController.excludedActivityTypes = [ UIActivityType.airDrop, UIActivityType.postToFacebook ]

    // present the view controller
    self.present(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: "I found this post Swift: share mp3 file via whatsapp but it also doesn't work for me." That's profoundly unhelpful. How, specifically and in detail, does it fail to work for you?

Comment: Sorry I update the post.

Comment: You should use URL instead of NSURL in Swift3

Comment: Hello, I changed to this but no luck.  var audioURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: temp_url!)
        let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [audioURL], applicationActivities: nil)

Answer (score -1):

I solve it with below code;

```
if(temp_url != nil){
let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [temp_url!], applicationActivities: nil)
        activityViewController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.view // so that iPads won't crash

        // exclude some activity types from the list (optional)
         let excludeActivities = [UIActivityType.airDrop, UIActivityType.print, UIActivityType.assignToContact, UIActivityType.saveToCameraRoll, UIActivityType.addToReadingList, UIActivityType.postToFlickr, UIActivityType.postToVimeo, UIActivityType.postToFacebook, UIActivityType.message, UIActivityType.postToWeibo]
        activityViewController.excludedActivityTypes = excludeActivities

        // present the view controller
        self.present(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: Using force-unwrap like that is a bad idea.

Comment: Are you saying that for temp_url?

Comment: Yes. Using force-unwrap is generally a bad idea, since you crash if the underlying optional contains a nil. I call it the "crash-if-nil operator"

Comment: I'm declaring it in the main so I'm using it in 3 other function. I don't know how to declare it without optional.

Comment: Optionals are fine. Force-unwrapping optionals (using `!`) is generally a bad idea, especially if you don't understand what it does

Comment: I add an If statement which checks temp_url. Is it what you say?